# How to tackle csv files in Python without Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I've been given a homework task to get data from a csv file without using Pandas. The info in the csv file contains headers such as...

1. work year:
2. experience level: EN Entry-level / Junior MI Mid-level / Inter- mediate SE Senior-level / Expert EX Executive-level / Director
3. employment type: PT Part-time FT Full-time CT Contract FL Freelance
4. job title:
5. salary:
6. salary currency:
7. salaryinusd: The salary in USD
8. employee residence: Employee’s primary country of residence
9. remote ratio:

One of the questions is:

For each experience level, compute the average salary (over 3 years (2020/21/22)) for each job title?

The only way I've managed to do this is to iterate through the csv and add a load of 'if' statements according to the experience level and job title, but this is taking me forever.

Any ideas of how to tackle this differently? Not using any libraries/modules.

Example of my code:

```
with open('/Users/xxx/Desktop/ds_salaries.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = f.readlines()
    for row in csv_reader[1:]:
        new_row = row.split(',')
        experience_level = new_row[2]
        job_title = new_row[4]
        salary_in_usd = new_row[7]

        if experience_level == 'EN' and job_title == 'AI Scientist':
            en_ai_scientist += int(salary_in_usd)
            count_en_ai_scientist += 1

avg_en_ai_scientist = en_ai_scientist / count_en_ai_scientist

print(avg_en_ai_scientist)
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: without using libraries this would be hard, but I think your approach works best. I know dataclasses-csv would be useful for this and for myself, in a dev branch in a separate repo I've been working on a high level approach to tackle this kind of task as well.

Comment: are you allowed to use builtin libraries at all - for example like the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: I think builtin modules are fine... another question asked which job location paid the highest salary - i managed to do that fairly easy by indexing location and salary, putting them into lists and using 'zip' to create one list with tuples containing both elements, then using 'min' and 'max' to find the highest and lowest.

Comment: In that case, you could use a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), then iterate over the data row by row, testing for certain values in certain columns (keys).

Comment: I suppose that's similar to the code I have above?

Comment: Well, it's treating each row as a dict, not a list, so it's somewhat different. Please [edit] your question and post 5-10 lines of your data, and I'll write up an example for you.

Comment: How explicit is the assignment, or is this a ‘think outside the box’ type project?  If the requirement says ‘no pandas’; does it also say ‘no sqlite’?  ;-)  Perhaps read the CSV into an in-memory sqlite database and perform the analysis that way.

Comment: Just pure python, no sqlite unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working out an example like this, I find it helpful to ask, "What data structure would make this question easy to answer?"

For example, the question asks

> For each experience level, compute the average salary (over 3 years (2020/21/22)) for each job title?

To me, this implies that I want a dictionary keyed by a tuple of experience level and job title, with the salaries of every person who matches. Something like this:

```
data = {
    ("EN", "AI Scientist"): [1000, 2000, 3000],
    ("SE", "AI Scientist"): [2000, 3000, 4000],
}
```

The next question is: how do I get my data into that format? I would read the data in with csv.DictReader, and add each salary number into the structure.

```
data = {}
with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        experience_level = row['first_name']
        job_title = row['last_name']
        key = experience_level, job_title
        if key not in data:
            # provide default value if no key exists
            # look at collections.defaultdict if you want to see a better way to do this
            data[key] = []
        data[key].append(row['salary_in_usd'])
```

Now that you have your data organized, you can compute average salaries:

```
for (experience_level, job_title), salary_data in data:
    print(experience_level, job_title, sum(salary_data)/len(salary_data))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I guess a good way to tackle this kind of problem is to reverse engineer it as you did - hadn't thought of this before, thanks.